# How to move folders with command line prompt in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt

Let's say we have next directory structure: `parent\exampledir\exampledir\<very complicated folder structure like node modules>`. By running only one command I want to have next structure: `parent\exampledir\<very complicated folder structure like node modules>`. How can I achieve this in command prompt?

I tried with: `move exampledir\exampledir .`, but I get a prompt asking me do I want to override exampledir. After I answer with Yes I get a message saying that access is denied. If I change the name of outer exampledir everything is fine and inner exampledir with all files and folders is correctly moved, but then there is one extra step where I need to delete outer exampledir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one command line, though technically it would be multiple commands using a FOR loop and then first renaming the source directory.  You can enter multiple commands on a single line using a semi-colon.  The following is written from my head so may not be technically accurate but should guide you to the correct way to write it:

```
d=blah\exampledir;REN "%d" "%d.bak";MOVE "%d.bak\%~nd" "%d"
```

This effectively moves the directory to a .bak, and then pulls the subdirectory of the same name back to the original name.  If you put this into a batch file, don't forget to escape the % signs with a second one.

Another option could be to add * after the directory name so you MOVE exampledir\exampledir* exampledir\

it may be possible that using Git for Bash, you could launch the shell and use the Linux mv command which may work

Finally, if you want to make sure you back up your batch files, create a free GitHub account and either store it in a repo or create a Gist for one off things

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this still doesn't answer my question. Maybe I wasn't clear when I sad "by running only one command". What I meant was only one command in command line like: move, xcopy, cd, dir... and options that come with that particular command. I didn't mean only one line (it doesn't matter if it's more than one line as long as it's one command).

Comment: Technically it can be a single command if you place the above into a batch file. A single command spanning multiple lines, a single command using a batch file or multiple commands in a single line achieves the same effect.  Not sure why you need to place that artificial limitation but maybe if you clarify that in your question it’ll help others who come to answer it.

Comment: People usually send me .zip files. When I unzip them I get directory structure as mentioned in my question. After a long time of unziping, renaming and moving files I got tired of all that so I wrote a batch file as you said. Than on one beautiful morning I bought and built my new PC and of course I forgot to copy batch file before throwing old HDD. And here I am. I know I can write a batch file, I know I can put ; to separate multiple commands, but I would really like if I could do it with one simple command. Fast, easy, everywhere... without any script.

Comment: I’ve added some other options which may work. But I think that’s the best you can hope for if you do lose your batch file. You may want to follow my suggestion of using GitHub to back up your batch files.